# Устаревшие значения

Tags: лексика

Задание для 9-классников.
Вот несколько отрывков из «Руслана и Людмилы» А. С. Пушкина:

Уже Фарлаф по граду мчится,

И шум на стогнах восстает...

В полях наездники мелькают,

Вдали подъемля черный прах ...

В устах открытых замер глас,

И пал без чувств он на колена...

Назовите 1) слова, отсутствующие в современном языке, приведя их значение, и 2) выступающие в иных значениях, нежели в современном языке, а также 3) устаревшие формы широко употребительных слов.

Одна девочка (из 20) ответила на все вопросы абсолютно верно. А  кто из нас сможет? Давайте попробуем без Гугла. Ну, думаю, на третий не будем отвечать, здесь всё ясно - колена, а вот 1 и 2...

Comment: Вспоминая себя в девятом классе, уверен, что заявил бы, мол, в моём современном языке все эти слова есть, а если у кого-то их нет, то ему надо заняться словарным запасом и разнообразием речи.

Answer (score 1):

(1)

стогна - площадь (это подсмотрел)

подъемля - поднимая

уста - губы

глас - голос (сохранились только полные старые выражения, напр. "глас вопиющего в пустыне")

(2)

(a) град: помимо метеор. явления (видимо, и ранее использовалось), используется при словообразовании для наименований совр. городов

(б) восстаёт (здесь поднимается): используется по отношению к форме социального протеста (восстание)

(в) наездник: используется в более узком значении - не просто "всадник", а мастер управления лошадью на публике (спортивная    "выездка", цирковые трюки, укрощение мустанга и пр.), либо любая женщина на лошади - "наездница"

(г) прах - не используется в значении "пыль"

(д) пал - используется с пафосным оттенком при упоминании о погибших на войне

(г) колена - используется при обр. мн. числа от технического термина (трубное колено и т.п.)

Comment: Правильно, но "наездник" и сейчас - либо верховой, либо управляющий коляской, и не только запряженной лошадью(на ипподроме), но и механической, например мотоциклом (или велосипедом).Впрочем, кто-то может быть уловит в последнем случае некую иронию.

Comment: Правильного ответа нет, комментировать пока не буду, пусть ещё кто-нибудь попытается.

Answer (score 1):

1. Слова, отсутствующие в современном языке: стогна – «площадь», подъемля – «поднимая».
2. Слова, выступающие в иных значениях, нежели в современном языке: восстать – в значении «подняться», прах – в значении «пыль».
3. Устаревшие формы широко употребительных слов - на колена вместо на колени.

А вот град, глас, уста - малоупотребительные, пассивный запас торжественной лексики, они не входят ни в одну группу, потому что они присутствуют в современном языке в отдельных пластах лексики в тех же значениях и в той же форме, которая была в старые времена. Признаюсь, меня удивила рассудительность ученицы. Она отвечала без подсказок, шпаргалок, сидя за первой партой, никуда не выходя.

Я бы вот "подъемля" отнесла к малоупотребительным, а она мне ответила: "Есть глагол - архаизм подъемлет, а деепричастия никогда не слышала". В ключах оказался именно такой ответ. Вот уж поистине ученик пошёл дальше учителя. Горжусь, что у нас такие есть (правда, я для неё только репетитор, но к олимпиаде готовила, так что какое-то отношение имею). Спросила её, откуда знает про "стогна", говорит, что не знала, но догадалась по контексту.

Значит, ещё не всё потеряно - растут лингвисты. Это обнадёживает.

Comment: Людмила, вы говорите, что "восстать - в значении  "подняться" прах - в значении   "пыль" выступают в иных значениях, нежели в современном языке. Но эти слова употребляются и в современном языке - в поэзии.  Если исходить из задания, то получаются, что именно это значения этих слова устарело. Но это ведь не так. Эти слова многозначны.

Answer (score 0):

Град - город, глас - голос, подъемля - поднимаясь, уста - губы, стогна (уст.) - стог.

Comment: Так что, слово "стогна" многозначное?  В одном ответе стогна - площадь, в другом - стогна (уст.) - стог

Comment: Стогна - ПЛОЩАДЬ( уст). В своем ответе я ошибся.